# Use Dos commands to copy file and preserve date in file name

Tags: batch-file, copy, cmd

I'm having trouble trying to copy and rename a file using only dos commands. I have a file of the format `myfile20130218` and want to copy and rename it to `some_other_file_20130218`.

I know I can use `copy source dest` but I'm having trouble with how to isolate the date and preserve it. I cannot guarantee that he date will be today's date so that is ruled out, the source file will always be the same name.

I can run either a series of commands or a batch script, but thing that that I am currently having trouble with, is after I find a match that I need to copy, using `myfile????????`, how can I now get those file names to pull the dates off them?

EDIT: for clarification I will be looking at files in a known directory, as above, I will know the format of the file name, and will only be checking a specific directory for it. The process that checks the directory is a ConnectDirect file watcher, so when a file is found matching `myfile20130218` I can fire off some commands, but don't know how to check the directory and get the name of the file present.

Comment: Powershell is not an option?  I think this would be difficult just using the standard windows command line tools.

Comment: No, the one thing I forgot to mention is this will be something that has to run from a ConnectDirect script, so basically a process that will trigger when it detects a match file name in a directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

`%oldname:~-8%` extracts the last 8 characters from `%oldname%` which are then appended to the new filename.

**Update:** If you can identify the file with an external program and then call the batch script with the file name

```
copyfile.cmd C:\path\to\myfile20130218
```

you could do something like this:

```
set oldname=%~nx1
set newname=%~dp1some_other_file_%oldname:~-8%
copy "%~f1" "%newname%"
```

**Update 2:** If you know folder and the format you could call the script with the folder

```
copyfile.cmd C:\folder
```

and do something like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%f in (
  'dir /b "%~f1" ^| findstr /r "myfile[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$"'
) do (
  set oldname=%~f1\%%f
  set newname=%~f1\my_other_name_!oldname:~-8!
  copy "!oldname!" "!newname!"
)

endlocal
```

**Edit:** Script breakdown.

- `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` enables variable expansion inside loops and conditionals.
- `for /f %%f in ('...')` executes the command between the single quotes and then loops over the output of that command.
- `dir /b "%~f1"` lists the content of the given directory (`%~f1` expands to the full path of the first argument passed to the script) in simple mode (no header, no summary).
- `findstr /r "myfile[0-9]...[0-9]$"` filters the input for strings that end with the substring "myfile" followed by 8 digits. The circumflex before the pipe (`^|`) escapes the pipe, because otherwise it would take precedence over the `for` command, which would effectively split the `for` command in half, resulting in an invalid command-line.
- `set oldname=%~f1\%%f` assign the full path to a matching file to the variable `oldname`.
- `set newname=%~f1\my_other_name_!oldname:~-8!` assign the full path to the new filename ("my_other_name_" followed by the trailing 8 digits from `oldname`) to the variable `newname`.
- `copy "!oldname!" "!newname!"` I don't need to explain this, do I?

Comment: That's what I want, but my question is how do I make this generic so that I can get 'myfile20130218' without having to specify it directly as above?

Comment: @dann You'd have to specify it somewhere, either as a parameter, contents of a file or any other way to do it. So, if you specify how you want it to get the name of the file, I'm sure someone will either edit it or make a new question.

Comment: @dann.dev What exactly are you looking for? Files that start with the string "myfile" followed by 8 digits? Do you know the location of the file? Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: Sorry about that, as above, I know the file name format, and will only be checking a single directory for it. The process will be called when a file matching the `myfile????????` is found.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Sorry the point is I will not know the file name, only the directory it will be in and the format of the name.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Now that does exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you, if you find time could you post a link to any references to it, or break down the the for loop declaration and matching criteria so I can understand what it's doing, only if you have time :)